# Reading JSON Object returned from API REST

Tags: javascript, json, rest, backbone.js

I'm feeling stupid asking the question, but I'm with it like 3 days ago... I built a php api rest, that returns a json encode info. The json that the api returns is correct, is something like that:

```
[
    {"pk_user":"1","name":"George","surname":"Littlewolf","profile":"Game designer - Developer"},
    {"pk_user":"2","name":"Anne","surname":"Carpenter","profile":"Developer"},
    {"pk_user":"3","name":"John","surname":"Sullivan","profile":"Designer"},
    {"pk_user":"4","name":"Judith","surname":"Lenders","profile":"Developer"},
    {"pk_user":"5","name":"Jason","surname":"Middleton","profile":"Manager"}
]
```

After that, I'm creating a backbone front-end to attack the api. I have developed only one view, that reads the json I wrote above. I have one **model (User)** and one **Collection (Users)** where I'd like to save the info read from the json info.

I'm going to put only the code of the render function of the view:

```
render: function() {
    var users = new Users();
    users.fetch();
    $.each(users['models'], function(i, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });


    this.template = _.template(template, {users : users});
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    return this;
}
```

Now, the console returns only what you see in the next image:

[image]

I'd like to access directly to the items, but i don't know why but all that I've tried is notworking... Thanks and excuse me for the newbie explanation... 
EDIT

I've [uploaded the code to a hosting](http://www.jordillobet.es/taskmanager/fe/) to everyone who want to see the problem "on live".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is an AJAX call so this:

```
users.fetch();
```

won't fill the collection right away, it has to wait for the server to respond. So when you go to look at `users.models`, there won't be anything there and your view ends up doing nothing.

The usual approach is to listen for events from `users` and render HTML in response to those events:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new Users;
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    // bind to other events as needed...
    this.users.fetch({ reset: true });
},
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(user) {
        // render the `user` model in here...
    });
}
```

Note the switch to [`this.collection.each`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) instead of messing around with the collection's `models` property directly.

Alternatively, use a success handler when you call `fetch`:

```
this.users.fetch({
    success: function(collection) {
        collection.each(function(user) {
            // render the `user` model in here...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you for the answer, not only have helped me to resolve the problem, but I also have understood how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want, but if you want to log the attributes of the User just do this:

```
$.each(users['models'], function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.attributes);
});
```

Comment: I've tried this solution too and don't work. I've uploaded the code so you can see the problem online.

Comment: sorry, I don't fully understand what is the problem. What I see in the code uploaded is that users will be empty as the code keeps running while `users.fetch()` is getting the JSON object from the server. Is this your problem?

Comment: The collection Users it's not empty actually. The problem is that I don't know how to access to the every user I've loaded inside Users. In fact, the thing that I'm printing on the javascript console is `users['models']`, and You can see that exist the data, but I don't know how to access to the everty User info. It could be something like you put on your first comment, but I don't know why doesn't work :(